# Downloading a file but getting permission errors

Tags: python

I'm trying to download a file but when it's trying to write to the current directory it gives a permission error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP User\Desktop\WWE Tool\MasterDownload.py", line 22, in <module>
    with open(x, 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\HP User\\Desktop\\WWE Tool'
```

Code:

```
MasterDownload = requests.get(url=Master, headers=Heads)

fpath = os.getcwd()

with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(MasterDownload.content)
```

I checked the current path and eveything looks fine, I just can't get around as to why it's not writing as I am an admin

Comment: based on the error message, my guess is the destination folder does not exist. maybe you want to update the file path to actually write to a file with extensions?  Further, given that it is windows, likely you won't have permission issues...

Comment: The folder exists, I printed the current path and it was correct, and how would I update the path to writing with extensions?

Comment: Just changed the extension and it worked, thanks @teng

Comment: accept an answer if it works.

Comment: I had a time limit so I forgot about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually trying to write to a directory (the process' current working directory - as obtained from `os.getcwd()`), not to a file. Try selecting an actual file in that directory to write to instead of the directory itself, and the issue might go away.